# Should I be able to add placeholder text in a custom view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

I have a pretty basic custom view that consists of a 2 TextViews styled in a particular way. I'm inflating the view from the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_line1"
        tools:text="10"
        .../>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_line2"
        tools:text="Reviews"
        .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I add this custom view to another layout in Android Studio via xml, the placeholder/tools text does not appear in the Android Studio preview. I'd like to see "10 Reviews" in the preview without actually setting the custom attributes which change these fields. I have imported the tools namespace in the layout containing the custom view.

Is there a way to do this? Am I creating this view incorrectly?

Comment: How are you including this in another layout? Does it show the textviews just not the tools text? And does the tools text show when you are viewing this layout on its own in a preview

Comment: I'm including the custom view in another layout via XML (i.e. `<com.me.StackedTextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"...>). It shows the TextViews as expected but not the tools text when viewing in preview.

Comment: I updated my question to be more descriptive. I agree it was a bit ambiguous :P

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, tools information is not preserved if you used the layout to inflate a custom view.

You can try using `isInEditMode` to populate the data using the informaion you get from AttributeSet